# Is it safe to mention the username/password in PHP code (since it will be executed server-side)?

Tags: php, security

I am writing a code in PHP that will access the database stored on the server. Is it safe to keep the login credentials in plain-text inside PHP or should I apply encryption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encryption isn't necassary, since PHP files are unreadable for clients. But if your server is hacked, the hackers could get that information. So, yes, try encrypting it.